# Angular / ionic Check for same page navigation event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a bottom menu that contains a few buttons that each link to a page using `navigate`:

```js
this.navigate(TimelinePath, 'back');
```

Then I have an overlay that checks for the path to test if it should close:

```js
this.routerSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.closeModal();
    }
});
```

This works, however there is an issue with it: If I am already standing on the page I try to redirect to, this event is not fired.

So my question is: How can I check whether the page that should be redirected to is already opened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is the [`onSameUrlNavigation`](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#onSameUrlNavigation) option that exists since Angular 5, in the `RouterModule` import.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
})
```

This will trigger the `NavigationEnd` and close your modal even if navigating to the same URL. Check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/onsameurlnavigation-demo) to see it in action.